# Create new column in pandas dataframe by calculation from previous index columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am new and learning pandas for data analysis. I have 2 columns data

```
A   B
1   2   
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

I want to create a third column C which result would be calculated by column B , by subtracting upper value with current one and dividing by current.

```
A   B   C
1   2   
2   3   0.33
3   4   0.25
4   5   0.2
```

for example first row value for C column is empty because there is no value above 2 .

```
0.33 = > 3 - 2 / 3 , 
0.25 = > 4 - 3 / 4 ,
0.2 = > 5 - 4 / 5 and so on
```

I am stuck while getting the upper value of current column. Need help how to achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use shift to shift the column and then the remaining operations are the regular ones (sub and div):

```
df['B'].sub(df['B'].shift()).div(df['B'])
Out: 
0         NaN
1    0.333333
2    0.250000
3    0.200000
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

This can also be done without chaining the methods, if you prefer.

```
(df['B'] - df['B'].shift()) / df['B']
Out[48]: 
0         NaN
1    0.333333
2    0.250000
3    0.200000
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Great Thanks Sir.

Comment: How to tackle NaN ?

Comment: @GhazanfarKhan Do you want to replace NaN with a value? Add fillna at the end: `df['B'].sub(df['B'].shift()).div(df['B']).fillna(0)` for example.

Comment: Yes some how empty string

Comment: `df['B'].sub(df['B'].shift()).div(df['B']).fillna('')` then. It will upcast the data type to object though. I wouldn't recommend if you want to use the column in further operations.

Answer (score 3):

## Edit for handling NaN and decimals.

```
df['C'] = (1 - df.B.shift() / df.B).map(lambda x: '{0:.2f}'.format(round(x,2))).replace('nan','')
```

Output:

```
   A  B     C
0  1  2      
1  2  3  0.33
2  3  4  0.25
3  4  5  0.20
```

Let's simplify and use the following with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas-series-shift) to get the previous value:

```
df['C'] = 1 - df.B.shift() / df.B
```

Output:

```
   A  B         C
0  1  2       NaN
1  2  3  0.333333
2  3  4  0.250000
3  4  5  0.200000
```

Comment: How to tackle NaN ?

Comment: @GhazanfarKhan What do you want to do with nan?  replace with 0?

Comment: @GhazanfarKhan for handling NaN and rounding.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply using `diff`

```
df2.B.diff()/df2.B
Out[545]: 
0         NaN
1    0.333333
2    0.250000
3    0.200000
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Comment: How to tackle NaN ?

Comment: add `.fillna(0)` or nay value you want replace NaN